# Android Studio formatting while keeping manual aligned items

Tags: android-studio

I am moving from iOS development to Android development (in Kotlin) using Android studio and I notice that when I "reformat code" that my manually aligned items in my code are removed.

I am used to write beautiful code like this:

```
enum class Difficulty2(val difficulty: Int) {
    unknown(0),
    red    (1),
    yellow (2),
    green  (3),
    brown  (4),
    blue   (5),
    pink   (6),
    black  (7)
}
```

but when "reformatting code" Android studio makes it this:

```
enum class Difficulty(val difficulty: Int) {
    unknown(0),
    red(1),
    yellow(2),
    green(3),
    brown(4),
    blue(5),
    pink(6),
    black(7)
}
```

Is there any way that I can tell Android studio to leave my manually aligned stuff alone when doing a reformat code?

Comment: And why isn't this beautiful?

Comment: Everybody has its own idea of what is beautiful I guess, however this does not answer the question.

Comment: That's why it's in the comment section

Comment: Point taken; I see no answers at all after some tile. I guess this is just not possible...